# jax-rs, jersey archetype, can't seem to use @WebListener

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jax-rs

I'm trying to launch a background task at the start of a restful service. However I can't seem to use neither `@WebListener` nor `@Schedule`. I thought it was a servlet version problem but it's the first time I use this archetype thing and jax rs.

I created the project on eclipse by right-clicking-> new project -> maven -> and I typed this for the archetype `jersey-quickstart-webapp`

my web.xml where it says version 2.5 (I changed it to 3) :

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.peti.rest.peti</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

That I changed to :

```
 <web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
```

my pom.xml is :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">



    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.peti.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>peti</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>peti</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>peti</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId> -->
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Neither can I use the interface `ServletContextListener`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went in project properties and made sure some of the project facets were correct.

Then I went back to check if I could import the interface by hovering my mouse, there wasn't a possibility to import it but there was a "fix" proposition under it which made a jar available. Then it worked. All in all easy fix but it took me a while.

or as peerskilled said just add this to maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You needed [this maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0)

Comment: @peeskillet indeed. If you want to post as answer I'll accept it.